# Bulk file renamer for gtk/gnome

Tags: software-recommendation, batch-rename

I know of `krename` but I'm wondering if there's a similar app that uses gtk/gnome libraries.

I also know of `Thunar` but I don't really want a file manager. I just want a bulk renamer.

Are there any applications that provide a GUI just for bulk renaming tasks?

Comment: At [this page](https://alternativeto.net/software/krename/) you have some alternatives to krename. Some of then are for linux.